# ajax jquery - success html response

Tags: ajax

I have an ajax form. I'm trying to print relevant message on success.

So jquery:

```
    //start ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            if (html == 1) {
                $('#getquotepopup').fadeTo('slow', 0, function(){$('#cboxLoadingGraphic').remove();});
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');
            }
        }
    })
```

and php on receiving end:

```
if (wp_mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
    // the message was sent...
    //for Ajax, create response .OK.
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

But problem is  if `(html == 1)` always gets evaluated false.

Can you please point me out the error?

Comment: What does the php on the receiving end actually return ? Check the response.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov if I run php manually it returns 1.

Comment: No, I mean, within the javascript, did you check the value of the `html` variable. If it's always 0, it probably means that your `data` parameters are not being passed correct.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov it actually returns empty :(

Comment: Ah, well there you go, that's the problem, make sure the parameters you're passing are in the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

try ussing "===1" instead of "==1"

Answer (score -1):

I would returning a text string such as 'SUCCESS' from your PHP script instead of a 1 or 0.

Pending that, I would also try the javascript comparison as if it were a quoted string:

e.g.

```
if( html == "1" )
```